# How to reference proprerty from sub objects with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, class, object, reference, this

i have to call a property in "object1" from sub object "object3", but this example doesn't work because the "this" keyword is referenced in "object2" and not "object1", do you know how to do this ?

```
function object1() {
   this.a = "hello world";

   this.object2 = function() {
      this.object3 = function() {
         alert(this.a); //prints "undefined"
      }
  };
}
```

try this example with:

```
var obj1 = new object1();
var obj2 = new obj1.object2();
obj2.object3();
```

thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function object1() {
    this.a = "hello world";
    var self = this;
    this.object2 = function () {
        this.object3 = function () {
            alert(self.a); //prints "undefined"
        }
    };
}
var obj1 = new object1();
var obj2 = new obj1.object2();
obj2.object3();
```

You have to store the `this` object, otherwise you will be accessing the `this` of the function `this.object3`'s scope

Comment: thank you, it was so simple and i'm so stupid XD thank you again :D

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes as scope changes. You need to save a reference of `this` for any new scope:

```
function object1 () {
    var first_scope = this;
    this.a = "hello world";

    this.object2 = function() {
        var second_scope = this;

        this.object3 = function() {
            var third_scope = this;
            alert(first_scope.a);
        }
    };
}
```